# How to make a list of all column-values from multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

Consider the following data frame:

```
> df
    a b
  1 1 4
  2 2 5
  3 3 6
```

I want to aggregate a list of all values from my data frame, like this:

```
> c(df$a,df$b)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

In my real data frame there are a lot of columns, so i need to select them by specifying a range. Naming every column would be impractical. I tried it like this:

```
> c(df[1:2])
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6
```

The result is a list of columns, not a list of all column values. How can this be achieved?

The ultimate goal is to make a frequency distribution of all values (the set of values is finite).

Comment: with `unlist` ? (`unlist(df[1:2])`)

Answer (score 1):

you probably want:

```
unlist(df)
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 
 1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thank you. I was sure the answer is simple, but I was not able to find it  within half an hour of searching various versions of the same question on Google or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

or with matrix:

```
c(as.matrix(df))
```